# Выборка нескольких значений в Excel

Tags: excel

В Excel имеем данные

> ```
> A B   C
> 1 Мяч Синий
> 2 Мяч Красный
> 3 Мяч Фиолетовый
> 4 Мяч Зеленый
> 5 Мяч Круглый
> 6 Фигурка новогодняя
> 7 Фигурка наклонная
> 8 Ведро   обычное
> 9 Ведро   необычное
> 10    Ведро   желтое
> ```

Интересует как можно из этого списка сделать выборку. Например, мне нужно, чтобы единовременно были выбраны все варианты для значения Мяч и значения Ведро. Через фильтр это задань нельзя (только одно значение), =ИНДЕКС(....ПОИСКПОЗ( ) ) тоже дает только первое значение в списке. Как обойти эти ограничения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первой строке - "шапка" таблицы.

*E1, F1* - для записи критериев отбора.

Дополнительный столбец с формулой в *D2*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(B2=$E$1;B2=$F$1);МАКС($D$1:D1)+1)
```

Формирование результирующей таблицы:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(1:1)>МАКС($D$2:$D$20);"";ИНДЕКС(A$2:A$20;ПОИСКПОЗ(СТРОКА(1:1);$D$2:$D$20;)))
```

Можно немного сократить формулу и вычисления- вынести *МАКС($D$2:$D$20)* в отдельную ячейку (например, *G1*).

Дальнейшая оптимизация - за счет применения функции *ВПР()*, но для этого доп. столбец должен быть размещен перед таблицей (например, в столбце *А*; при этом данные таблицы сдвинутся вправо):

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(C2=$E$1;C2=$F$1);МАКС($A$1:A1)+1)
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(1:1)>$G$1;"";ВПР(СТРОКА(1:1);$A$2:$D$20;СТОЛБЕЦ(B:B)))
```

Без доп. столбца сформировать требуемую таблицу тоже можно. Но это будет формула массива:

```
=ИНДЕКС(A$2:A$20;НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ(($B$2:$B$20=$E$1)+($B$2:$B$20=$F$1);СТРОКА($2:$20)-1);СТРОКА(1:1)))
```

Ввод такой формулы заканчивается одновременным нажатием трех клавиш: *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*; формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками - *{=формула}*.

Убрать ошибку в строках, для которых данных не нашлось:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(1:1)>СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$20;$E$1)+СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$20;$F$1);"";ИНДЕКС(...))
```

Формула массива производит много "лишних" вычислений, поэтому на больших таблицах лучше применять первый вариант (с доп. столбцом).